# Populating ListView from Database without Using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, populate

I have a seperate DatabaseHandler("db") Class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper BUT NOT ACTIVITY which means this is a seperate class file which is not related to any activity. If you ask why i have such a class not in activity because i like keeping my files organized.

So i have listview in a fragment and i have a "DatabaseHandler.getAllRows()" function in that  class which returns a "List" Object. Then i want to use this list to populate my listview.

So when this class is a seperate class which is not related to any activity, i can't use simplecursorAdapter since it wants a context in paramteres part when creating with new(i tried to send parameter as context but didnt work) so i need to use something else....

I can change return type, i can use another thing instead of listview.. just give me a good advice for how to populate listview or show table rows NICELY.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real simple solution, you can store your rows as an array, and use `ArrayAdapter` to display them. You can override the getView to display the results in your preferred way.

If this solution is not good enough, I think you will have to implement your own `Adapter`, which might be a good idea anyway.